# Laravel 7 Multiple Authentication using Passport

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am working on Laravel application that requires generating access token for multiple users. I am using  Laravel Passport with Password Grant to issue token.  I have followed the Laravel documentation but it seems I am doing something wrong as I got redirected to Login route when I try to call my API endpoint (Student) with Postman. I later found out that the redirection is coming from the middleware I created but I still don't know what went wrong

> auth.php

```php
        'guards' => [
                'web' => [
                    'driver' => 'session',
                    'provider' => 'users',
                ],
        
                'api' => [
                    'driver' => 'passport',
                    'provider' => 'users',
                    'hash' => false,
                ],
               
                'api-student' => [
                    'driver' => 'passport',
                    'provider' => 'students',
                    'hash' => false,
                ]
    ];
    
    
         'providers' => [
                'users' => [
                    'driver' => 'eloquent',
                    'model' => App\User::class,
                ],
                'students' => [
                    'driver' => 'eloquent',
                    'model' => App\Student::class,
                ],
                 
            ],
```

> api.php

```php
    Route::post('auth/getlogin', 'Api\StudentController@authenticate')->middleware('auth:api-student');
    
    //Api\StudentController
    public function authenticate(Request $request, Student $user)
        {
            $credentials = [
                'username'=>$request->username,
                'password'=>$request->password];
          
            if(!Auth::guard('api-student')->attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'message'=>'Error'
                ], 401);
            }
             
            if(Auth::guard('api-student')->attempt($credentials)){
                $user = Auth::guard('client');
                $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
                return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
            }
            else{
                return response()->json(['error'=>'Username or password incorrect'], 401);
            }
        }
```

Comment: welcome to SO .. what error  you getting .?

Comment: I am getting redirected to my login route instead of being issued the access token

Comment: add header `"Accept":"application/json"` then it will not redirect

Comment: Thanks. Its not redirecting anymore . But I am getting {"message":"Unauthenticated."} after I called the endpoint

Comment: remove  middleware from here `auth/getlogin` it should be public api so anyone can login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `middleware` so anyone can login

```php
Route::post('auth/getlogin', 'Api\StudentController@authenticate')->middleware('auth:api-student');
```

to

```php
Route::post('auth/getlogin', 'Api\StudentController@authenticate');
```

you applied `middleware` here so before doing any action it checking route if `auth` or not

Comment: Thanks. But now i got    "message": "Method Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.". Does it mean I didn't call the Auth correctly?

Comment: The attempt method is part of the `SessionGuard` you cannot use `Passport` just generate token and send .